# Rails - How to Convert HTML to TEXT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for a way to convert HTML to text. I tried using sanatize to strip out HTML tags but that fails as some HTML has tags like:

```
<pre>adasdadadad</pre>
```

Which is text output where with sanatize it removes the tag and the text is lost.

Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "the text is lost"? Are you saying `"<pre>adasdadadad</pre>".sanitize` yields an empty string?

Comment: yes It does in what I'm seeing. Is that not right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [strip_tags](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/strip_tags).

That links says it is deprecated but [this](http://www.daokaous.com/rails3.0.0_doc/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#M002836) says it works for rails 3.

Or as Paul correctly points out you might to try an [updated API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags).

Comment: That link is old. You want: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags

Answer (score 3):

As pointed here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags

strip_tags method not functioning in controllers, models, or libs

It comes up with an error about white_list_sanitizer undefined in the class you’re using it in. To get around this, use:

ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags('string')
To shorten this, add something like this in an initializer:

```
class String
  def strip_tags
    ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(self)
  end
end
```

then call it with:

```
'string'.strip_tags
```